# how to spec createQueryBuilder() in controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpspec

I'm writing phpspec test for controller
In action I am calling another method with this:

> $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();

I cannot pass this in phpspec. 
What I'm getting is

> method `Double\ObjectManager\P7::createQueryBuilder()` is not defined

Have you got any suggestion how to spec it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't spec something, it's a indicator you have a bad design. In your case you should never create query builders in your controllers. Controller should be only a clue between different services.

For doctrine queries create repositories!

Comment: you are indeed right, i just mindlessly uses bundle code sample, yes I will refactor this, thanks!